# How to open an Emacs bookmark in a new frame?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs I can do <kbd>C-x 5 C-f</kbd> or <kbd>C-x 5 f</kbd> to find a file in a new frame. I want to do something similar but for bookmarks. How can I jump to a bookmark in a new frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `bookmark-jump-other-window` which you can clone and modify to create the function `my-bookmark-jump-other-frame`:

```lisp
(defun my-bookmark-jump-other-frame (bookmark)
  "Jump to BOOKMARK in another frame.  See `bookmark-jump' for more."
  (interactive
   (list (bookmark-completing-read "Jump to bookmark (in another frame)"
                                   bookmark-current-bookmark)))
  (bookmark-jump bookmark 'switch-to-buffer-other-frame))
```

Bind that function to a key chord of your liking and use it to open bookmarks in another frame, e.g. like that:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-5 b") 'my-bookmark-jump-other-frame)
```

Note that `my-bookmark-jump-other-frame` still needs `bookmark.el` and its functions. Make sure the appropriate functions are loaded in your startup file, e.g.:

```lisp
(require 'bookmark)
```

or

```lisp
(autoload 'bookmark-completing-read "bookmark"
 "Prompting with PROMPT ...[rest of docstring (optional)]")
```

Comment: That seems to work. Could you please include an appropriate way to bind a key for completeness? I figure that `C-x C-5 b` is an appropriate bind since it seems unbound and it is similar to the normal jump to bookmark, `C-x r b`, and also to find file in new frame.

Comment: You can e.g. use `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-5 b") 'my-bookmark-jump-other-frame)`.

Comment: I have encountered a problem with your solution. If I try to use it before I have used bookmarks in any other way during a session I get "list: Symbol's function definition is void: bookmark-completing-read". However, if I jump to a bookmark some other way, e.g. `C-x r b` and then try `M-x my-bookmark-jump-other-frame` it works. Can this be solved?

Comment: A `(require 'bookmark)` in your startup file should do. If you don't want to load bookmark.el unconditionally on each startup you could also use `(autoload 'bookmark-completing-read "bookmark" "Prompting with PROMPT ... (plus rest of docstring from bookmark.el (optional))")`.

Comment: Could you please include that info and a full description of the `autoload` solution in the answer? I am unfamiliar with how to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to jump to a new frame, from a bookmark in the bookmark menu/list, *without a prompt*.

But u-punkt's explanation was helpful in constructing this new function. I cloned the existing command associated with `RET`, and bound it to the unused `C-RET` locally to mode.

You can describe the original key with `C-h k RET`. Tracking down the code for `bookmark-bmenu-this-window` is not hard, then use u-punkt's strategy to write the following:

```
(defun my-bookmark-bmenu-other-frame (&optional use-region-p) ; Bound to `C-RET' in bookmark list
  "Select this line's bookmark in a new frame.
See `bookmark-jump' for info about the prefix arg."
  (interactive "P")
  (bmkp-bmenu-barf-if-not-in-menu-list)
  (bookmark-bmenu-ensure-position)
  (let ((bookmark-name  (bookmark-bmenu-bookmark)))
    (bmkp-jump-1 bookmark-name 'switch-to-buffer-other-frame use-region-p)))
```

For the keybinding, `bookmark-bmenu-mode-map` is not defined until `bookmark+` is loaded, so I use an `eval-after-load`,

```
(eval-after-load 'bookmark+ '(define-key bookmark-bmenu-mode-map 
                              (kbd "<C-return>") 
                              'my-bookmark-bmenu-other-frame))
```

## EDIT

If you need something that works when `bookmark+` is not installed, try the following,

```
(when (locate-library "bookmark+")
  '(eval-after-load 'bookmark 'bookmark+))

(if (locate-library "bookmark+")
    ;; then
    (defun my-bookmark-bmenu-other-frame (&optional use-region-p) ; Bound to `C-RET' in bookmark list
      "Select this line's bookmark in a new frame.
See `bookmark-jump' for info about the prefix arg."
      (interactive "P")
      (bmkp-bmenu-barf-if-not-in-menu-list)
      (bookmark-bmenu-ensure-position)
      (let ((bookmark-name  (bookmark-bmenu-bookmark)))
        (bmkp-jump-1 bookmark-name 'switch-to-buffer-other-frame use-region-p)))
  ;; else
  (defun my-bookmark-bmenu-other-frame ()
    "Select this line's bookmark in other frame."
    (interactive)
    (bookmark-jump (bookmark-bmenu-bookmark) 'switch-to-buffer-other-frame))
  )

(eval-after-load 'bookmark '(define-key bookmark-bmenu-mode-map 
                              (kbd "<C-return>") 
                              'my-bookmark-bmenu-other-frame))
```